# Why isn't the name of my device changing?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

I changed the name of my new Kindle Fire within my Amazon account by going to `Manage My Kindle -> Manage My Devices`. Everything seems to have gone fine on the account side, but the upper left hand corner of my Fire still just says "Abby's Kindle". Lamest name *ever*. It's been about 24 hours since I made the change in my account. Why hasn't it changed? What step am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the "sync" button in the status bar menu? Allegedly that can help (source: http://androidadvices.com/change-kindle-fire-device/#axzz1hwM4JV2R).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't tried this yet, I think you should try syncing your device. To sync the device, you tap on the settings button on the top right and select `sync`.